# Prepositions that go with "accuracy"

Tags: prepositions, nouns, collocations

> We need to improve the accuracy with which such errors are detected.

I usually use "accuracy" with a relative pronoun as shown above. After looking up dictionaries, I found that the sentence above can be rewritten as follows:

> 1. We need to improve the accuracy in detecting such errors.
> 2. We need to improve the accuracy of detection of such errors.

I am confused whether other prepositions such as "to" and "for" can be used, for example as follows:

> 3. We need to improve the accuracy to detect such errors.
> 4. We need to improve the accuracy for detection of such errors.

Which sounds most natural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accuracy refers to the degree of correctness or precision of some action or by extension of that which performs the action.

> The rockets returned to their landing platform with great accuracy.

We can speak of **accuracy** as an abstraction, as a quality of actions or things that perform actions. But in actual contexts it does not exist apart from the action or the thing taking the action. So it is not idiomatic to say:

> We need to improve **the accuracy** to detect such errors.

—not unless that sentence is understood to be elliptical:

> We need to improve the accuracy [of our detecting device] to detect such errors.

So that if we were to say

> In order to detect such errors, we need to improve the accuracy.

a reasonable question would be "The accuracy of *what* in particular?" if the thing that can be accurate in its action was not already known from context.  But if it is known, the sentence is elliptical, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's *results accuracy* vs *device accuracy* **for** getting (in order **to** get) the wanted results.

1-2: Detecting errors with improved accuracy (a need in more *accurate results*).

3-4: Improving the method or device accuracy in order *to make it possible to detect* (= to find) small or some specific errors. 
The prepositions **to**/**for** agree here with the *purpose* of improving the accuracy.